# Сделать переменные, массивы и другие данные метода main доступными в других методах

Tags: java

Вопрос по Java (от новичка).

Есть метод main, который через сканер получает от пользователя 3 переменные, заполняет некоторые массивы, проводит кое какие вычисления.

В этом методе нужно посчитать f(x);

Решил сделать другой метод для подсчета f(x) - в который мы будем передавать X и получать return - ответ после вычислений и в зависимости от ответа - дальше использовать метод main так или иначе.

Проблема в том, что в новом методе, нужно иметь доступ ко всем переменным и массивам метода main (собственно для тех же вычислений).

Как сделать все переменные и массивы метода main доступными другим методам в классе ?

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Либо объявить их вне метода main, а выше и сделать их статическими, либо передавать их в параметрах необходимому методу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - это вынести переменные из метода:

```
public class sovet {
    static int[] ints = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            ints[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вынес их из метода main.

Answer (score 1):

3 решения.

1. как описано статические поля в классе куда будет записываться.
2. создать экземпляр класса и завести в нем не статические поля.
3. передавать в метод как параметр.

Самое худшее решение имхо это статические поля(вариант 1). Ибо твой метод для рассчета значения функции намертво привязывается к этим полям. Но оно же самое быстрое.

Имхо методы которые рассчитывают значения функции по хорошему должны получать входные данные как параметры, а константы брать с полей.

Answer (score 0):

В классе завести статические переменные и использовать их и в методе main и в других методах этого класса.

Comment: Спасибо. Вынес их из метода main.